# What to do when .where() can't cast data back to original type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following changes my ids to `float`, and I've been trying to cast that column back to `int` since the `try_cast` parameter isn't working out.

```
(df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left', indicator=True)
    .where(lambda x: x._merge=='left_only', try_cast=True)
    .get(['id'])
    .dropna()
)
```

In the past I would set it up this way:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left', indicator=True)
merged['id'] = merged['id'].astype(int)
merged[merged['_merge']=='left_only']
```

I'm new to Python, and I've been exploring chaining operators to speed up my exploration in jupyter notebooks.

1. How would I perform this operation inline?
2. Is the `where` method the best method to use? It feels wrong to `dropna` in order to filter the results I want.

Comment: Please include samples for `df1` and `df2`. It will 1) illustrate your issue, and 2) allow people to test code and answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is the `where` method the best method to use?" Actually, we can do better with `query`.

Also, from your comments and my understanding of `df.where`, I believe the integers are actually upcasted to floats by this function, so taking that out of the equation will mean further casting is no longer required.

```
(df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left', indicator=True)
    .query('_merge == "left_only"'))
```

Comment: So much better. With `query` the cast appears to be unnecessary for my use case. Thanks for helping me find the right operator for this situation!

Comment: @wolfhoundjesse Interesting, I think the `where` introduced NaNs. Will update my answer, thanks!